# Why does my checkbox's text continue to show when I hide or slideUp the checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have created a checkbox in the code-behind like so:

```
Checkbox ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr = new CheckBox();
ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr.Text = "Send PDF to this email address?";
ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr.ID = "ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr";
```

...and am endeavoring to conditionally show or hide it in the client/jQuery code based on which of two radio buttons the user selects:

```
$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentForSelf]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        . . .
        $('[id$=ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr]').slideUp();
        . . .
    }
});

$(document).on("click", '[id$=rbPaymentForSomeoneElse]', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        . . .
        $('[id$=ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr]').slideDown();
        . . .
    }
});
```

The problem is, it is only the checkbox itself that is being hidden - the text ("Send PDF to this email address?") still displays. Isn't the text part of the checkbox, and it should show/hide along with it?

Here is the generated HTML:

```
<input id="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl24$g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33$ctl00$ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr" /><label for="ctl00_ctl24_g_5f3fedca_19f7_4bc3_b84e_efbef0c48a33_ctl00_ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr">Send PDF to this email address?</label>
```

This makes me think the text is a quasi-independent element (a "label" but affiliated/associated with the checkbox). So do I need to give the text property an ID and reference that and hide it/slide it up separately?

What do I need to do to make the checkbox recognize its text as part and parcel of itself?

Comment: could you make an example of your problem? Perhaps with https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Yes, the label is separate from the checkbox itself.  It has it's own beginning and end tags outside of those for the checkbox.  You have two opions:  1.  Wrap them both in some element (like a div) and hide the div as opposed to the checkbox.  2.  Separately target and hide the label (you could use $(...).next('label') to target it (where the $(...) hits the checkbox).

Comment: Text isn't part of input. `input` is void element, it doesn't contain any content. Hide the label instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('[id$=ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr]').slideUp().next().slideUp();
```

and

```
$('[id$=ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr]').slideDown().next().slideDown();
```

The above will hide the label as well.

The text of the checkbox is contained is a span the immediately follows the checkbox element. Therefore you need to use `next()` to get the following element and hide it as well.

Comment: No it won't. It looks like `label` is wrapping `input`. In this case, it should be: `$('[id$=ckbxSendPDFToThisEmailAddr]').parent().slideDown()`

Comment: @A.Wolff Look at the HTML provided, the label is after the input `<input id="id" type="checkbox" name="name" /><label for="id">Send PDF to this email address?</label>`

Comment: Works perfect; will mark as answer ASAP (five minutes).